# NSArray Image doesn't show in ScrollView

Tags: ios, nsarray, scrollview

`NSArray` image have:

```
2012-08-15 10:12:39.687 test[4200:11103] (
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/1.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/0.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/0.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/2.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/2.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/2.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/2.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/1.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/1.jpg",
    "http://192.168.1.165/Images/Demo/1.jpg" )
```

And code .m:

```
dispatch_async(htvque, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: tophotfilm];

        NSError* error;

        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                               options:kNilOptions 
                                                 error:&error];

        NSDictionary *list = [json objectForKey:@"List"];


        NSMutableArray *arrPoster =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSString *po in list)
        {
            NSString *poster = [po valueForKey:@"Poster"];
            [arrPoster addObject:poster];

        }
        myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrPoster];
        NSArray *colors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], 
                           [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor magentaColor],
                           [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor], 
                           [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor grayColor], nil];
            //NSLog(@"%@",colors);
            NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
                //NSLog(@"%@",myArray.count);
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            CGRect rect = imageView.frame;

            rect.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
            rect.origin.y = 0;
            rect.size = scrollView.frame.size;

            [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        }

        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width *
        myArray.count,scrollView.frame.size.height);
        pageControl.currentPage = 0;
        pageControl.numberOfPages = myArray.count;
        [super viewDidLoad];
    });
```

With NSArray colors, it's working ok, but NSArray image has some error.

---

scrollview don't display listimage, it show first image, anybody know why...

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>                   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) 
>                   {
>                       //NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
>
> ```
>                 NSURL *urlImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
>                 //NSLog(@"%@",urlImage);
>                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage]];
>                 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
>
>                 CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
>                 rect.size.height = imgHeight;
>                 rect.size.width = imgWidth;
>                 imageView.frame = rect;
>                 imageView.tag = i;
>
>                 //rect.size = scrollView.frame.size;
>                 [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
>             }
>
>             scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
>             scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
>             scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
>             scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width *
> ```
>
> myArray.count,scrollView.frame.size.height);
>                   pageControl.currentPage = 0;
>                   pageControl.numberOfPages = myArray.count;
>               });

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of code

`NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i];`

You image name would be just 1, 2 etc., not the image names printed in the log,

It should be something like

`[myArray objectATIndex:i];`

Comment: hi ashkbabuy, I fixed the url and get the image but they do not appear in the UIImage maybe its into "dispatch_async(htvque, ^{..//}"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `imageNamed:` which can only be used for images inside your project, and if I understood your question you are trying to access them from a server. Try this `UIImage` method: `imageWithData:`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: thanks ohr, I used code for u and its running ok, but its don't show list image in scrollView i don't know why --- this link code: 
            http://mocku.ps/hwcqot